# Write on a ISO9660 partition

Tags: linux, partitioning

Why can I write on a persistent manner on an ISO partition ? Is it possible to exploit that capability ?

I have a liveUSB, and like every liveUSB it mounts a persistent /var/crash and /var/log. But those partitions (for me sdb3 who's on EXT4) keep the files writed between reboots. But where does it write it if my entire stick is an ISO read only partition ?

And I have a vfat partition too (4Mo sdb2) who keeps files between reboots and that the system does not mount automatically

I really don't understand what happen

EDIT : Just did a write test and i can write on all free space on the USB stick

Comment: What's mounted on `/var/log`?

Comment: A partition of my USB stick named sdb3 (who not appear on GParted), i don't know his size, Linux writes in it normally the log like every other linux, but those writed files are persistent

Answer (score 0):

ISO is for *inmutable* filesystems (on CD, DVD and so), it makes no sense to try to change it. You assemble a set of files/directories, and create an ISO image from them. That installation media were designed to boot from CDs (ISO images), but nowadays are written to (modifiable) USB sticks is just another endearing remainder of times past. Like the insistence of my other Linux installation to find a diskette drive on boot, and set up a modem...

Comment: I'm totally aware of that fact and that today UEFI can read many partition format and search for an EFI folder by himself, so it's way more modular. But the problem is that many programs give a persistent partition only for ubuntu and i'm not on ubuntu. And i found nowhere the method to manually do a persistent partiton, or better, make all the drive modifiable like a hard drive...